# AIMesh failure...process of elimination

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, cat6, power-over-ethernet, mesh-networking

I have an Asus AIMesh system. The main router is an Asus RT-AC88U. I have two satellites off the RT-AC88U, both of them are RT-AC66U B1's. They are connected / the backhaul is ethernet-CAT6, not wireless backhaul.

In addition, I have POE in the system. I have a passive POE inserter and a passive POE splitter, so a POE dongle on each end of the CAT6 cables. One of the satellites has a 50 foot Cat6 cable, the other has a 75 foot Cat6 cable.

One of the two RT-AC66U B1's works flawlessly -- like a charm. The second RT-AC66U B1 satellite, with the 75 foot run, isnt working.

I got on chat with ASUS and they said it sounded like a HW issue with the router and I returned it and got a replacement; so now I know its not a HW issue with the router.

One thing I notice with the misbehaving router, is the LED for the "internet/network" port on the router kind of blinks, its not solid. the router is getting power/DC current but perhaps not a clear or stable ethernet signal?  The offending router appears to work, briefly (the Wifi LED lifts turn on) then it reboots itself.

I had the router in question in my study before I hooked it up to the 75 foot cable and the POE gear, with a shorter ethernet cable. It worked perfectly! Then when I hooked it up the to the 75 foot cable and the POE gear, it didn't work.

So, what could it be? Where is the broken link? The POE dongles and CAT6 cable work just fine with the other satellite.  I am thinking the misbehaving satellite router must have an issue with the specific 75 foot CAT6 cable or with the specific POE dongles.

I think the simplest thing I could do is bring the POE splitter and router back into my study and hook it up via a different CAT6 cable. If it works, then I presume the issue is the 75 foot cable. If it doesn't work, I presume it is the POE dongle?

I am wide open to suggests on how to indentify the broken link! Help!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Tried switching the satellite routers yet? You could do this to detect problems with the connection.

Comment: I just took out all the POE gear for the offending satellite, and it appears to work well.  So, it could be the POE dongles are bad.  The other satellite uses the same dongles but only a 50 foot cable and it has always worked fine.